# Macro to copy and special paste rows of values down the table and stop at the right place (before a blank row)

Tags: vba, macros

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjcjm.jpg)

I am not sure how to write a macro to special copy the values and paste down the table as long as there is something in the column to its left. (instead of set a fixed range)

The end result should be like in this jpeg.
Much appreciated for the help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7nm.jpg)

Comment: Macro recorder: ctrl+c, left, ctrl+down, right, ctrl+shift+up, ctrl+v. Analyze recorded macro and refine. Learn VBA while you are at it.

Comment: Thanks! This is a rather elegant solution but I am looking for something that will be able to adjust to the number of rows...say next time, it might have more or less rows. I am also applying this across at least 50 worksheets each may have different number of rows down the columns.

Comment: This is why crtl+down is used: it will always go all the way down. Recording macros is also a great way to learn VBA programming, so you won't have to depend on others doing your job for you for free...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("P2:T2").Copy
    .Range("O3", .Range("O3").End(xlDown)).Offset(,1).Resize(,5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
End With
```

Comment: Thank you user3598756. I just tried your code. It only copied and pasted one more row.

Comment: there was a 4 where there ought to be a 5. see edited answer

Comment: did you get through it?

Comment: yes, it did work. But if there were more rows of data (simulated by adding a few more rows). These rows of data were deleted.

Comment: my answer works as per your _original_ question and attached screenshots. So following this site rules 1) please accept my answer as the solution. 2) If you have to expand/change the question, then post a new one. thank you

Comment: Please accept my thanks. Your solution did work for what I had posted, but it was not the ultimate result I was looking for. It was probably my error for not putting my need through clearly. If my rows of data stayed the same every time, this will be perfect! I liked your short lines of code, it was great. But looking at my problem, I was prone to yarnspinner's solution as I think yarn probably understood what I was trying to get to though I probably did not explain clear enough. I am faced with a dilema as the number of my data changes and fluctuate from month to month.. to be cont.

Comment: and also across different products. Hence I need a macro coding which can cater for different lines. I needed to copy and paste the data down and adaptable to each scenario...how many data rows I have on the left ie. column O. I know this application will be very useful for those doing graphs and that's precisely what I was aiming at. Doing a graph with 2 and 3 standard deviations around the mean for scientific use. But your solution did work brilliant but not just to what I was looking for. Please accept my thanks as I know your codes will also come in great use. Thank you!

Comment: I must say you guys are brilliant and knows the macro so well!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the solution. But I still can't understand your new issue. My solution does adapt the range down to the actual first row in column "O" which precedes an empty one. if the "fluctuation" of your data is different than  consider starting a new question to thoroughly address the issue

Comment: Let me test this again. I also thought it strange because your coding looked good to me. When I ran the sub the first time, it did exactly that. So I went back to the table and add a few more lines of data filling column I to O. As I ran it the 2nd time, it erased the newly added rows to my surprise but still managed to copy and paste the data down. I will have another look now...

Comment: Yup, still deleted my newly added rows of data. Not sure what is deleting them. I wish I could show you.. not sure how or if I can post more pics here. I am new so maybe my privilege is not high enough to do that.

Comment: Sorry... it was me again... I should not have added your codes into my existing sub. Something was interfering with it. In fact, your code worked beautifully. Can I actually change it to activesheet rather  than specifiying which sheet I am working with?

Comment: PS This reminds me to separate a filtering process in my existing sub with other coding functions. Best to separate them into different sub. This is my learning to take home.

Comment: _"Can I actually change it to activesheet rather than specifiying which sheet I am working with?"_  Yes you can

Comment: @Gary: what happened?

Comment: All good! Thanks..Sorry for delay in replying.